# Sagemaker From RecordIO To Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, amazon-sagemaker

While preparing my data for Sagemaker's Factorization Machine implementation for training, I am successfully using the function `write_spmatrix_to_sparse_tensor` ([source code](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/amazon/common.py)) to transform my data from a sparse matrix to the recordio format expected by Sagemaker's factorization machine implementation.

Example where I have limited import statements to the provided function:

```
import os
import io
import boto3
import sagemaker.amazon.common as smac

def write_recordio(array, y, prefix, f):
    # Convert to record protobuf
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    smac.write_spmatrix_to_sparse_tensor(array=array, file=buf, labels=y)
    buf.seek(0)

    fname = os.path.join(prefix, f)
    boto3.Session().resource('s3').Bucket('bucket_name').Object(fname).upload_fileobj(buf)
```

An example snippet of the argument `array` which are features:

```
   (0, 990290)  1.0
   (0, 1266265) 1.0
   (1, 560338)  1.0
   (1, 1266181) 1.0
   (2, 182872)  1.0
   (2, 1266205) 1.0
   ...
```

An example format of y which is my target:

`[1. 1. 1. ... 3. 1. 5.]`

`write_spmatrix_to_sparse_tensor` works as intended with the above function and input. After training my model, I then use Sagemaker's [Batch Transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/batch-transform.html) to receive a `.out` file with many outputs of type `<class 'record_pb2.Record'>`

Examples:

One record from `write_spmatrix_to_sparse_tensor` output:

```
features {
  key: "values"
  value {
    float32_tensor {
      values: 1.0
      values: 1.0
      keys: 990290
      keys: 1266265
      shape: 1266394
    }
  }
}
label {
  key: "values"
  value {
    float32_tensor {
      values: 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

One record from batch transform output (`.out`) file where many of these records exist):

```
label {
  key: "score"
  value {
    float32_tensor {
      values: 1.5246734619140625
    }
  }
}
```

So now I have a file originally written using `write_spmatrix_to_sparse_tensor` and an output from `transformer.transform` and I would like to get back to my original sparse matrix format from these files. Essentially, if the function `write_sparse_tensor_to_spmatrix` existed, what would it look like?

Answer (score 3):

There must be a better way. But what I learnt is to read the values from the output file. Change the data type and reform them to a proper format. Example of reading the values

```
data.label['score'].float32_tensor.values
```

The `data` here is one record in your output file. The type of the result is 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedScalarContainer' but you can convert it to Python list or NumPy array or any data type that fits your model.